# How to write 2D list to a txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write 2D below to a txt file called readme.txt, but I keep on receiving error.

```
report_storage = [
    ['      ', '| G02  ', '| G05  ', '| G07  ', '| G08  ', '| G10  ', '| G25  '],
    ['------', '|------', '|------', '|------', '|------', '|------', '|------'],
    ['P001  ', '|  1   ', '|  0   ', '|      ', '|  --  ', '|  1   ', '|  0   '],
    ['P067  ', '|  1   ', '|  1   ', '|  0   ', '|      ', '|  --  ', '|  1   '],
    ['P218  ', '|  0   ', '|  1   ', '|  1   ', '|      ', '|      ', '|  1   '],
    ['P101  ', '|  0   ', '|  0   ', '|  1   ', '|  1   ', '|  --  ', '|  1   '],
    ['P456  ', '|  1   ', '|  1   ', '|      ', '|  1   ', '|      ', '|  0   '],
    ['------', '|------', '|------', '|------', '|------', '|------', '|------']
]
```

My code:

```
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(report_storage)
```

My code Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\FinalCodingChallenge\test4.0.py", line 70, in <module>
    f.write(report_storage)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
```

My aim is to get the result below to appear on readme.txt

```
      | G02  | G05  | G07  | G08  | G10  | G25  
------|------|------|------|------|------|------
P001  |  1   |  0   |      |  --  |  1   |  0   
P067  |  1   |  1   |  0   |      |  --  |  1   
P218  |  0   |  1   |  1   |      |      |  1   
P101  |  0   |  0   |  1   |  1   |  --  |  1   
P456  |  1   |  1   |      |  1   |      |  0   
------|------|------|------|------|------|------
```

Comment: `f.writelines(report_storage)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a matrix/ 2D-array to a text file python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692703/how-to-write-a-matrix-2d-array-to-a-text-file-python)

Answer (score 1):

`report_storage` is a list (of lists).

`write()` only accepts a string as parameter, not a list. Hence the `TypeError`.

You need to convert the list into string. First, convert each item in the list into string by joining cells with empty string between each cell.

```py
report_storage_lines = [''.join(line) for line in report_storage]
```

Then join the lines with a linebreak character between each line:

```py
report_storage_text = '\n'.join(report_storage_lines)
```

Then you can write to file:

```py
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(report_storage_text)
```

Comment: Hi Leon, understood. Thank you for your help. appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can only write `strings` to a file. Your `report_storage` is a `list` of `strings`.

You need a loop to iterate over your list:

```
f = open('readme.txt', 'w')
for i in report_storage:
    tmp = ""
    for j in i:
        tmp += j
    f.write(tmp + '\n')
```

Comment: | G02  | G05  | G07  | G08  | G10  | G25  ------|------|------|------|------|------|------P001  |  1   |  0   |      |  --  |  1   |  0   P067  |  1   |  1   |  0   |      |  --  |  1   P218  |  0   |  1   |  1   |      |      |  1   P101  |  0   |  0   |  1   |  1   |  --  |  1   P456  |  1   |  1   |      |  1   |      |  0   ------|------|------|------|------|------|------

Comment: @Miracle What's that?

Comment: Hi Jakob. Understood and thank you for your help. But the result appear to be like this in my readme.txt. not the format that I wanted. I want them to be line by line.

Comment: @Miracle Oh, I forgot \n. Check my edit.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it! Now I understand what to do

Answer (score 0):

The `f.write()` syntax, as mentioned above, only accepts a string as an argument. Suppose you have a list of lines to write, then you would need to do `'\n'.join(lines)` so that you have a multi-line string representing the file contents to save.

That said, either of the below approaches should work to get you the desired output to a file.

The first approach uses a `list` comprehension to convert the list of lists to a string:

```
f.write('\n'.join([''.join(sub_list) for sub_list in report_storage]))
```

I personally prefer this approach, which uses the `map` builtin for slightly shorter syntax:

```
f.write('\n'.join(map(''.join, report_storage)))
```